# Fit a table within \textwidth in Latex

Tags: latex

I have a table that is wider than the \textwidth of my document. (I don't want to change the \textwidth.) 
I want to force the table to be fitted in \textwidth by wrapping the last (rightest column) column's text.
This is my code for my table:

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Extracted Features used in Meta-Learning} \label{sample-features}
\label{tbl:features}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\textwidth,center}{|l||l|}
{\textbf{FEATURE}}  &{\textbf{DESCRIPTION}} \\
\hline \\
n.examples & Number of examples \\
n.attrs & Number of attributes \\
prop.symbolic.attrs & Proportion of symbolic attributes \\
prop.missing.values & Proportion of missing values \\
class.entropy & Class entropy \\
avg.mutual.information & Average mutual information \\
prop.h.outlier & Proportion of continuous attributes with outliers \\
avg.attr.entropy & Average attribute entropy \\
avg.symb.pair.mutual.infor & Average mutual information between pairs of symbolic attributes \\
avg.abs.attr.correlation & Average absolute correlation between continuous attributes \\
avg.skewness & Mean skewness of attributes \\
avg.abs.skewness & Mean absolute skewness of attributes \\
avg.kurtosis & Mean kurtosis of attributes \\
canonical.correlation.best.linear.combination & Canonical correlation of the best linear combination of attributes to distinguish between classes \\
relative.prop.best.linear.combination & Proportion of the total discrimination power explained by the best linear combination \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

The result of this code is the following document:

[image: Latex results]

The part in the right side of the red line (added by myself) should be wrapped.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer. I hope it can help you:

Using package `tabularx` as follows:

```
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
.
.
.
\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Caption}
\label{tbl:tbl}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
\toprule
Item 1 & Item 2 \\
\midrule
Item 1 description & Item 2 description \\
.
.
.
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

In my case the solution is as follows:

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Extracted Features used in Meta-Learning} \label{sample-features}
\label{tbl:features}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\textwidth}{|X||X|}
\toprule
{\textbf{FEATURE}}  &{\textbf{DESCRIPTION}} \\
\midrule
n.examples & Number of examples \\
n.attrs & Number of attributes \\
prop.symbolic.attrs & Proportion of symbolic attributes \\
prop.missing.values & Proportion of missing values \\
class.entropy & Class entropy \\
avg.mutual.information & Average mutual information \\
prop.h.outlier & Proportion of continuous attributes with outliers \\
avg.attr.entropy & Average attribute entropy \\
avg.symb.pair.mutual.infor & Average mutual information between pairs of symbolic attributes \\
avg.abs.attr.correlation & Average absolute correlation between continuous attributes \\
avg.skewness & Mean skewness of attributes \\
avg.abs.skewness & Mean absolute skewness of attributes \\
avg.kurtosis & Mean kurtosis of attributes \\
canonical.correlation.best.linear.combination & Canonical correlation of the best linear combination of attributes to distinguish between classes \\
relative.prop.best.linear.combination & Proportion of the total discrimination power explained by the best linear combination \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Hi! Had you tried some _paragraph_ alignment like `l p{.6\textwidth}` instead of `X X`?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654531/cannot-get-the-table-that-i-need-in-latex/30833770#30833770