# Cannot get the table that I need in latex

Tags: latex

I am having some problems with a table in latex. Basically the label "Conclusion" does not even appear in the table and the text in it is not how I wanted it and it is not all displayed. Does someone know why?

```
\begin{tabular}{rr}

\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Conclusion}} \\

\midrule

Blume (1974: 638) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{"the weighted unbiased estimator is probably the safer to use"                                                 } \\
Fama (1996: 419) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{"The estimate of Et (R) that produces an unbiased Pt is a combination of the asset's past compound and average simple returns"} \\
Jacquier et al (2003: 52) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{"unbiased estimates of future portfolio value require that the current value be compounded forward at a weighted average of the arithmetic and geometric rates"                     } \\
Indro and Lee (1997: 89) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{"the horizon-weighted average [...] is also more efficient than other estimators in the presence of negative autocorrelation, time-varying, and stationary variances"} \\
Koller et al. (2005: 308) & " an [weighted] estimator proposed by Marshall Blume best adjusts for problems caused by estimation error and autocorrelation" \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
```

Here is my code. I would thank you very much if someone could have a look at it and tell me what I do wrong.

Comment: Hi, can you post your preamble too? Which packages are you using?

Comment: For LaTeX, there is a specific StackExchange site: [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). You are more likely to get answers on LaTeX there.

Comment: MattAllegro I am only using the package array for the moment. Should I get some other packages to make the code work?

Comment: No, only booktabs for the top, mid and bottomrule.

Comment: Are you sure this text should even be in a table? Doesn't look like tabular data to me. Don't repeat the sins of 90s web design in regular text documents...

Answer (score 1):

In your code there's a bit of confusion with right alignment and left `multicolumn`s. I suggest you switch from left to *paragraph* alignment, **not to exceed the page width**. In this case you have something like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{70mm}}

\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Literature}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Conclusion}}\\

\midrule

Blume (1974: 638) & "the weighted unbiased estimator is probably the safer to use"\\
Fama (1996: 419) & "The estimate of Et (R) that produces an unbiased Pt is a combination of the asset's past compound and average simple returns"\\
Jacquier et al (2003: 52) & "unbiased estimates of future portfolio value require that the current value be compounded forward at a weighted average of the arithmetic and geometric rates"\\
Indro and Lee (1997: 89) & "the horizon-weighted average [...] is also more efficient than other estimators in the presence of negative autocorrelation, time-varying, and stationary variances"\\
Koller et al. (2005: 308) & "an [weighted] estimator proposed by Marshall Blume best adjusts for problems caused by estimation error and autocorrelation"\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This code, with no `\centering` or `table` environment, positions as follows the table in the default A4 paper.

[image: output page]

By the way, here I didn't take any care of the quotation marks.